# SQLite.Swift error : Value of type 'Connection' has no member 'key'

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlcipher, sqlite.swift

XCode 12.5.1
As title, I got an error.
And I use Carthage to install SQLite.swift.
SQLite.swift version is 0.13.0
carfile here:

```
github "stephencelis/SQLite.swift"
```

```
import Foundation
import SQLite
import SQLCipher

let db = try Connection("\(dbName_UserData)")

let code: String = self.getEncryptCode()
try? db.key(code) //Value of type 'Connection' has no member 'key'
```

[image]

What's wrong with my issue?
I follow the document to use `key` to encrypt database.
[image]

Comment: It's in https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Sources/SQLite/Extensions/Cipher.swift so do you have the flag enabled in your config `SQLITE_SWIFT_SQLCIPHER` to have that method? According to the Podspec (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/SQLite.swift.podspec) you need to have the subspec `SQLCipher` for Carthage, I don't know how it's configured.

Comment: If you look at Cipher.swift you will notice `#if SQLITE_SWIFT_SQLCIPHER` and `import SQLCipher`. Somehow you are going to have to include SQLCipher into your project.